# How could I modify postgres function source code

Tags: postgresql, psql

when I do:

```
  \df+ functionName;
```

I get the function source code.

How could I edit this code?

I edited the function, using \ef+, but then how would I save/execute it?

Comment: You have to recreate the function with `CREATE OR REPLACE functionName ....`

Comment: I edited the function, using \ef+, but then how would I save/execute it?